# Using a gift with condition for Matanot L'Evyonim

Tags: halacha, purim, tzedakah-charity, shlichus-agency, conditional-stipulation

(Related to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26543/is-indirect-matanot-levyonim-ok)) I understand one can give matanot l'evyonim by way of a messenger.

I was given a gift this year for Purim -- someone gave me a $5 check with the recipient space left blank and told me to give it to my charity of choice on Purim.

In terms of fulfilling the obligation of matanot l'evyonim, does being given a gift on the condition that it be given as matanot l'evyonim allow the eventual donation to be considered mine (because of the gift) or the giver's (because of the condition)? In such a case, is the recipient of the gift-with-condition viewed as merely a messenger or as the owner?